# Eager loading of non-singleton collections

Tags: python, orm, group-by, sqlalchemy

I'd like to load collections of repeated objects. My model looks like this:

```
Item -> Identifier
```

I'd like to load (eagerly) collections of Items that share the same Identifier, but ignore the vast majority of collections that contain one item or less. The ORM relationship is set up in both directions (Identifier.items and Item.identifier). The SQL should look like something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE identifier_id IN (
    SELECT identifier_id FROM Item GROUP BY identifier_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sub-query, this can be achieved as following:

```
q = (select([Item.identifier_id, func.count(Item.id).label("cnt")]).
     group_by(Item.identifier_id).having(func.count(Item.id)>1)).alias("subq")
qry =  (session.query(Item).join(q, Item.identifier_id==q.c.identifier_id))
print qry # prints SQL statement generated
items = qry.all() # result
```

Comment: Is the query against the `__table__` necessary in this approach, more performant?  Why not just join `Item` to another query of `Item`?

Comment: It results in one query (instead of 3 in your original solution) and loads **only** required `Item` objects into the `session` without `Identifier` objects. I would definitely say it is more efficient.

Comment: .. the query does not need to use `Table` objects though: updated the answer to use Objects directly...

Comment: Thanks! I had to change to a `session.query(Identifier)` to prevent repetition and I added a `subqueryload(Identifier.items)`. This join on a sub-query trick is really effective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version I am finally using:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import count
from sqlalchemy.orm import subqueryload
# …

repeats = (
    select(
        (Item.identifier,
        count(Item.identifier)))
    .group_by(Item.identifier)
    .having(count(Item.identifier) > 1)
    .alias())
for identifier in (
    sess.query(Identifier)
        .join(repeats, repeats.c.identifier==Identifier.value)
        .options(subqueryload(Identifier.items))
):
    for item in identifier.items:
        pass
```

(Identifier is now mapped against a select and not backed by a database table, which makes import a bit faster too)